# Android, Drupal & DrupalCloud or Android-xmlrpc tutorial?

Tags: android, json, drupal, xml-rpc

Does anyone know of a good tutorial for any of the above?

I need to send data to Drupal from and Android phone.

Data is stored in XML but can be converted to JSON easily.

Then it needs to be stored in a user's profile.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the [Drupal Views module](http://drupal.org/project/views) to achieve this. It's a very powerful module which allows you to run complex queries on your database and produce output in virtually any format.

Here's some information about using [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) and [Views Datasource module](http://drupal.org/project/views_datasource) to [produce JSON data](http://groups.drupal.org/node/11387).

If Views Datasource isn't any use, then [Views Bonus Pack module](http://drupal.org/project/views_bonus) may be an alternative.

Hope that helps.

Comment: My understanding is that the OP wants to send data _from_ Android phone _to_ Drupal, while your suggestion is geared at the other direction. So while your suggestions might also benefit him, you could add a Link to the Services module for the reverse direction - http://drupal.org/project/services.

Comment: The comment is correct. I need to send data from an Android phone to drupal. I have tried to read through the documentation of the services module and have even used both DrupalCloud and Android-XMLRPC as a base but i cannot get either to work. - Is there a working example of 'node.get' in Java? Just something simple so that i can figure out the parameters etc. thanks

Answer (score 0):

THe reason DrupalCloud wasn;t working was due to my version of PHP 5.2.14.

The solution was to put the key values in double quotes as that is what JSON is expecting

```
bnvp[0] = new BasicNameValuePair("nid", "4"); 
bnvp[0] = new BasicNameValuePair("nid", "\"4\""); 

mPairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("method", "system.connect")); 
mPairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("method", "\"system.connect\""));
```

etc

Also, make sure all services modules are enable and the proper permissions are set.

Comment: Hey Matt, I am in the same boat and I am desperate for answers. It sounds like you figured out how to upload data from Android to Drupal.
Would you please give me some detailed directions, pleassssse!?