# Creating drupal web services for android

Tags: android, web-services, json, drupal, xml-rpc

I have been struggling particularly with this module in setting up xmlrpc.
I am using services 6.2 and enabled xmlrpc in site building -> module

Then I downloaded this library: http://code.google.com/p/android-xmlrpc/

For the purpose to keep it simple and just to see the implementation there is no security feature involved no API key or session key and even the anonymous user can visit [this link](http://www.mydomain.com/services/xmlrpc).

The following is the code which I am using in my android application to get data:

```
XMLRPCClient client = new XMLRPCClient("http://mydomain.com/infra2/drupal-.19/services/xmlrpc");

try{
    Log.d("SUM",""+client.call("node.get",2));
}catch {
    e.printstacktrace();
}
```

I am getting the complete data of node 2 here but it is not in XML format. Moreover, if I use the following  code:

```
Log.d("SUM",""+client.call("node.get",2,"user"));
```

to get particularly the user who created node 2. I am getting an error, but in drupal framework I can use both of the parameters to filter the content.

And when I use BasicNameValuePair like suggested in this link :-

[Android, Drupal & DrupalCloud or Android-xmlrpc tutorial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813628/android-drupal-drupalcloud-or-android-xmlrpc-tutorial)

The output which I get is following :

```
{uid=1, body=welcome , data=a:0:{}, type=panel, last_comment_name=, changed=1305012450, panels_node={did=1, pipeline=standard, nid=4, css_id=}, title=Welcome, created=1301322449, name=admin, revision_uid=1, taxonomy=[Ljava.lang.Object;@46378f28, tnid=0, vid=4, comment_count=0, files=[Ljava.lang.Object;@463776d8, status=1, nid=4, moderate=0, format=1, log=, picture=, sticky=0, promote=1, last_comment_timestamp=1301322449, teaser=welcome , revision_timestamp=1305012450, translate=0, language=, comment=0}
```

which is in simple php format and not xml

I have also tried to get the same working with views module and using views data source module to get the output in xml and json and it is working well.
But in this case i have to set the access to anonymous user as well and since my android application will be using the api calls to unsecure urls the major issue will be security.
So if someone could provide me the method to loginto the drupal website via android using httpurlconnection even that would serve the purpose.

Thanks in advance

I get following in my log cat and when I use BasicNameValuePair to pass the parameters.

The following are the errors which i get:

```
09-21 13:09:59.793: WARN/System.err(18690): java.io.IOException: Cannot serialize nid=4
09-21 13:09:59.803: WARN/System.err(18690):     at org.xmlrpc.android.XMLRPCSerializer.serialize(XMLRPCSerializer.java:99)
09-21 13:09:59.803: WARN/System.err(18690):     at org.xmlrpc.android.XMLRPCCommon.serializeParams(XMLRPCCommon.java:36)
09-21 13:09:59.803: WARN/System.err(18690):     at org.xmlrpc.android.XMLRPCClient.methodCall(XMLRPCClient.java:250)
09-21 13:09:59.803: WARN/System.err(18690):     at org.xmlrpc.android.XMLRPCClient.callEx(XMLRPCClient.java:170)
09-21 13:09:59.803: WARN/System.err(18690):     at org.xmlrpc.android.XMLRPCClient.call(XMLRPCClient.java:281)
09-21 13:09:59.803: WARN/System.err(18690):     at com.drupal.DrupalActivity.onCreate(DrupalActivity.java:34)
09-21 13:09:59.803: WARN/System.err(18690):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1069)
09-21 13:09:59.803: WARN/System.err(18690):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2751)
09-21 13:09:59.803: WARN/System.err(18690):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2803)
09-21 13:09:59.803: WARN/System.err(18690):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:135)
09-21 13:09:59.803: WARN/System.err(18690):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2136)
09-21 13:09:59.803: WARN/System.err(18690):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-21 13:09:59.803: WARN/System.err(18690):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
09-21 13:09:59.803: WARN/System.err(18690):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
09-21 13:09:59.803: WARN/System.err(18690):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-21 13:09:59.803: WARN/System.err(18690):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-21 13:09:59.803: WARN/System.err(18690):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-21 13:09:59.803: WARN/System.err(18690):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-21 13:09:59.803: WARN/System.err(18690):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-21 13:09:59.803: WARN/System.err(18690): org.xmlrpc.android.XMLRPCException: java.io.IOException: Cannot serialize nid=4
09-21 13:09:59.803: WARN/System.err(18690):     at org.xmlrpc.android.XMLRPCClient.callEx(XMLRPCClient.java:237)
09-21 13:09:59.813: WARN/System.err(18690):     at org.xmlrpc.android.XMLRPCClient.call(XMLRPCClient.java:281)
09-21 13:09:59.813: WARN/System.err(18690):     at com.drupal.DrupalActivity.onCreate(DrupalActivity.java:34)
09-21 13:09:59.813: WARN/System.err(18690):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1069)
09-21 13:09:59.813: WARN/System.err(18690):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2751)
09-21 13:09:59.813: WARN/System.err(18690):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2803)
09-21 13:09:59.813: WARN/System.err(18690):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:135)
09-21 13:09:59.813: WARN/System.err(18690):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2136)
09-21 13:09:59.813: WARN/System.err(18690):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-21 13:09:59.813: WARN/System.err(18690):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
09-21 13:09:59.813: WARN/System.err(18690):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
09-21 13:09:59.813: WARN/System.err(18690):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-21 13:09:59.813: WARN/System.err(18690):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-21 13:09:59.813: WARN/System.err(18690):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-21 13:09:59.813: WARN/System.err(18690):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-21 13:09:59.813: WARN/System.err(18690):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-21 13:09:59.813: WARN/System.err(18690): Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot serialize nid=4
09-21 13:09:59.813: WARN/System.err(18690):     at org.xmlrpc.android.XMLRPCSerializer.serialize(XMLRPCSerializer.java:99)
09-21 13:09:59.813: WARN/System.err(18690):     at org.xmlrpc.android.XMLRPCCommon.serializeParams(XMLRPCCommon.java:36)
09-21 13:09:59.813: WARN/System.err(18690):     at org.xmlrpc.android.XMLRPCClient.methodCall(XMLRPCClient.java:250)
09-21 13:09:59.813: WARN/System.err(18690):     at org.xmlrpc.android.XMLRPCClient.callEx(XMLRPCClient.java:170)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would actually suggest to look at REST, it's much easier to do than XML-RPC

Comment: client requirement either xml or json :( anywaz if i am unable to find an answer then i will move on to REST i have never played with REST before

Comment: I've had quite a bit of joy with the services module in the past and XMLRPC has always been fine...what format is the data coming back in currently from your call to `client.call("node.get",2)` if not XML? Is it just plain text? Are the values on a single line or split over multiple lines? Would you be able to post that output in your question? Sorry to bombard with questions it'd just be good to get a little more information

Comment: i have edited it... u can check the question again

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a for loop , I think before that you have to get the size and store it and then make it as a count in the for loop.

```
coutnt=0;
count=getname().getsize(){of the item}

for(;count;){
   put the value inside the loop.
}
```

Comment: i know the logic... i am not just getting the data in xml format... please read the questions carefully